# What is the antonym for OK?

Tags: translation, computing

I am trying to translate a web application, where if a specific condition is met it is necessary to write

`x < y : OK`

whereas, if not, one writes:

`x < y : KO`

This is a short message meaning that for the test “x < y”, “OK” means “all correct” (the condition is satisfied), and “KO” means “you should fix this, it is not satisfactory at present” (as the condition is *not* satisfied).

*So, what can be used to replace “KO” in English?*

Possibilities:

- `x > y: KO!`
- `x > y: NOK!`
- ??? what other short abbreviation/word in “standard” English could be used in that context?
- Are there differences between US and British usage?

***NB***

The best antonym suggested at [thesaurus.com](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/ok) is “bad”/“BAD”, but are there perhaps better options?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135356/discussion-on-question-by-serge-what-is-the-antonym-for-ok).

Answer (score 2):

It is not entirely clear to me whether the requested antonym is to be read by programmers or by the public. However, assuming that a two- or three-letter acronym is required, I would suggest:

> **NG** — No Good

This is included in the list of [NG acronyms in the “Free Dictionary”](https://acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/NG) and at [Abbreviations.com](https://www.abbreviations.com/NG) has a rating of 5/5 (suggesting that it is widely understood).

Personally, when checking a list of items against some criterion using pencil and paper, I would use the alternative:

> **NBG** — No Bloody Good

However “bloody” is a (mild) swear word that is used in Britain but not North America, so I imagine it is less likely to be generally understood. It scores [3/5 at Abbreviations.com](https://www.abbreviations.com/NBG).

*Footnote*

It has been suggested in a comment from @AndyBonner that there is *no* antonym to “OK”. It is true that what I have suggested is not as “clever” as the French “KO”, but the definition of antonym is [“a word of opposite meaning”](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/antonym) without any further stipulation or requirement. So I would maintain that it’s OK to use “NG” as an antonym of “OK”.

Comment: Ingenious attempt to answer the question. But I'm not sure how widely used NG really is or how scientific Abbreviations.com's method is: if you have to tell people that something is widely known, that suggests it's not really widely known.

Comment: @StuartF — My obvious difficulty is that if I understand an abbreviation I don’t know if others do. Hence in providing an answer I need to include some external reference relevant to usage. That I have done in a measured manner. For once a straw poll of list members in comments might be helpful. I encourage that.

Comment: remark about first sentence of the answer, "for programmers" I would not care to find an "good" antonym here, the short label is to identity a state of a form or control, to display to the user near the "wrong" field.